# Update SQL Database tables from the execution of Views against another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups

This is basically my scenario:

- I have a relational database which contains lots of tables and million of rows on each table.
- Search on this database is quite slow for some big queries so I have created several views that does some massaging on the data and some calculations and it provides me the exact data that I need by joining tables, etc...
- Now that I have the views, I can run super easy queries against them and extract the exact information I need very easily. However, if I do that at runtime whenever the user clicks on a button from my website, it takes quite a lot of time and the user can get some timeouts. It is because regardless I am using a view that simplifies my life, the query is being executed against the same heavy and huge database...

What I would basically love to do is to have a second database (which will be connected to my front-end, instead of the current database) where I can have just the data I am interested in from the Views that I've created on the initial database (which is the exact data that I need) but I have no idea how to achieve that.

1. Should I create some store procedures that gets executed against the second database and then update the tables of the second database with the new data? How could I do that? I already have created the second database with the tables that the view produces but I need to start bulking that data and I don't know how to first bulk the initial data and second, how to increment the data as soon as the first database starts to grow...
2. Also, I think a great idea would be to update the second database as soon as the first database is modified by a back-end tool that fills the database in. Is that possible? Triggers is what I need? How could I do that?

Any pointers and examples will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think creating seconds database itself is a bad idea

Comment: The usual way of fixing performance issues with select statements is indexes. try to look at the execution plan of the queries you run and see what indexes can you add.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure what you meanby indexes. Curently, the way I search on the database is by doing X number of JOIN (where the JOIN is done on a ID column) and then the View I execute is just 

SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE column1Id = id AND column2Id=id, etc....

I am always joining and querying by IDs that are defined in the database so not sure if that's what you mean by index?

Comment: I was able to improve the search by adding indexes but also making the query a bit lighter. Thanks! :)

BTW. Why my original question is a bad idea?

Comment: If you didn't even know what indexes were, you are in no way qualified to be querying a database this size. You need to sit down with some database books including at least one on performance optimization. and get educated on databases.  Your original idea was a bad one because it would add a lot of extra workload to the database for basically no reward and it would be very complicated and take an expert to get right and not end up with bad results, unsynched database and unhappy users. There are probably 100 different performance enhancement to try before you would even consider this route.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting an easy way to load that second DB with Data from your views you can run and insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO [secondDB].[dbo].[table_name]
(ColumnNames,...,N)

SELECT * 
FROM View
WHERE column1ID = ID
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use log shipping.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190640.aspx

All transaction from the main server will be shipped (hence the name) to the secondary server almost right away or with a delay of your choice.

However, view do make your life easier but performance issue are most likely due among over things to bad design/model, missing indexes, fragmented index, bad statistics, too many indexes or useless indexes. 
Have you looked at this as well?